# Is there a document type for MongoDB update documents?

Tags: mongodb, api, mime-types

JSON has `application/json`, JSON Schema has `application/schema+json`, JSON LD has `application/ld+json`. Do Mongo update documents, such as:

```
{
  $push: {
    array: 'thing'
  }
}
```

Have a document type, or mime type?